# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-karaf

I try to integrate Spring into OSGI Karaf and I have encountered a problem.
I make a good WAB file and then I install it. After the installation when the web container (Apache Felix) tries to parse spring-servlet.xml I have the fallowing exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
```

I have read almost every thread on this but I did not found any solution.
The file spring-servlet.xml is in /WEB-INF/spring/.

The file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="xyz"/>
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

pom.xml file

```
<!-- Spring core & mvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: what jars have you packed in WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: I have all the spring related jar files like web, webmvc, beans, core, context

Comment: does the spring context jar version match with schema (i.e. 3.0 in your case)? Does your app server lib folder has any different version of spring libraries? In your schema location you have pointed context and beans to 3.0 version but mvc points to default which is 4.1, it might not be a problem but try adding correct version to schema location.

Comment: I use spring 3.1.0 should I add 3.1 to schema ?

Comment: your schema points to 3.0 not 3.1 if your jar versions are 3.1 then correct the version for schema.

Comment: Modified right now but still the problem persist

Comment: try adding: <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I already have this declared. I have update my question with my pom file

Comment: Might want to compare your solution with a known-to-work solution, either all-in-one-war: https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples/war-spring        Or depending on external Spring, Spring-DM libraries: https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples/war-spring-osgi

Comment: I have used this example but I have another exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller . Some how seems that some of the jars are not deployed correctly to the Karaf. I don't see any apparent reason for this because looking into the MANIFEST file everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Basically the problem was that in feature.xml file of Karaf I did not installed all spring features and through all I mean all core, aop, servlet etc..